# How do you monitor a solr server with god, instead of respawning bundle sunspot-solr start

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr, god

The issue is that the command I use to start sunspot, `bundle exec sunspot-solr start`, itself spawns a solr server, which is the actual process that needs to be monitored, not the original command.  If I just set the start command, then it continually tries to respawn sunspot-solr start, which is unnecessary because the underlying solr process is still running.  Any idea how I can properly monitor this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start` command forks Sunspot into the background. You may prefer to use the `run` command instead, which leaves Sunspot's bundled Solr server running in the foreground. That should be more compatible with tools like Foreman, Upstart and god.